# How to continue PHP loop if you get a Warning?

Tags: php

OK so i have a list of urls and one of them is missing which is all good but how do i continue the loop instead of it stopping and giving me a warning error

```
foreach ($AllVideoThumbnails as $thumbnail) {
    try {
        GenerateImageCache($thumbnail['youtubethumbnail']);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
        // continue;
    }
}
```

And one the one with the image missing it gives this error

```
Warning: exif_imagetype(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X8AurWRkRpo/hqdefault.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in C:\wamp64\www\ModelHurdV2\ImageCache.php on line 400
```

And there is no image but I want to the finish the loop and just that error al together

this is the contents of Generate Image Cache

```
   require_once 'ImageCache.php';
    $imagecache = new ImageCache\ImageCache();
    $imagecache->cached_image_directory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cached';
    $cached_src_one = $imagecache->cache($imageUrl);
```

And this is the cache I am using 
https://github.com/nielse63/php-image-cache

Comment: You need to show us the content of `GenerateImageCache`. If you can't, `set_error_handler()` can help. In general, try to handle the situation inside called function and throw an exception there. Don't try to "catch" warnings, this is not their purpose.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Added bit more details

Comment: Just check in your loop if the file/stream exists before calling your function.

Comment: Have you tried removing the exception handling and just putting an "at" sign in front of the `GenerateImageCache()` function to supress the errors? e.g. `@GenerateImageCache($thumbnail['youtubethumbnail']);` (also, see [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) for more info).